# Precise interpretation of "in excess of"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I'd like to have some precision on the meaning of "in excess of" in following sentence.

*Commissions **in excess of 180%** of quota in a given fiscal year will be calculated at 0.3x of the base rate.*

Imagine that the quota is $100,000. Does **in excess of 180% of quota** means:

- Commissions over quota + 180% quota = $280,000 or,
- Commissions over $180,000?

Comment: _In excess of_ simply means _more than_ or _greater than_. 180% of X is 1.8 times X, not 2.8 times X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"180% of quota"* is *1.8 * quota*.

Hence, *In excess of (180% of quota)* just means *> 1.8 * quota*, which is your second option.

The alternative - your first option - would be *"180% **over** quota"*.